# My rectangle sometimes moves when I run my java program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I should be able to move the rectangle with the arrow keys but after running the program a few times the rectangle does not move. To make the rectangle move I close Netbeans and reopen it. Then the rectangle is able to move but it stops moving after a couple tries. I want to solve this problem so I can make changes.

```
package project;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

//KeyListener is use with keyboard
public class main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this); //for animation
    int x = 50, y = 50, velX =0, velY = 0; 

    public main()
    {
        tm.start(); //starts timer
        addKeyListener(this); //this refearing to KeyListener
        setFocusable(true); //enable KeyListener
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); //shift or tab is not use so F
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x,y,50,50);
    }        

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (x<0)
        {
            velX = 0;
            x = 0;
        }    

        if (x>500)
        {
            velX = 0;
            x = 500;
        }    

        if (y<0)
        {
            velY = 0;
            y=0;
        }  

        if (y>300)
        {
            velY = 0;
            y = 300;
        }    

        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;

        repaint(); // repaint rectangle 
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int c = e.getKeyCode(); //get key

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) // VK_Left is left arrow 
        {
            velX = -3;
            velY = 0;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP) // VK_UP is up arrow 
        {
            velX = 0;
            velY = -3; // means up 
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)  
        {
            velX = 3;
            velY = 0; 
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)  
        {
            velX = 0;
            velY = 3; 
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) //when you stop pressing 
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 0; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        main m = new main();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
        jf.setSize(600,400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: KeyListeners are very finicky when it comes to focus, and you sometimes have to jump through hoops and kludges to get them to work well, such as  having to call `requestFocusInWindow()` on your main JPanel after creating the GUI. Better to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Could you help me edit my program? I just started learning Java.

Comment: No. This is not how you learn, nor is this appropriate an appropriate thing to ask on this site.

Comment: One other problem: you should call `setVisible(true)` only ***after*** adding all components to the JFrame, thus it should be the last line of your main method. This is quite important and could contribute to your problems.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry about that. First question here...

Comment: That does it! Thank you so much for all your help. Sorry to give you a hard time.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).